# Need to export multiple dicts of dataframes to Excel based on a common key

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to create several dataframes from independent data sets and then export all of the dataframes to Excel based on common keys. I will have a variety of dataframes with different column  structures for many keys (people), and in the end I want to have one file for each person with all of the dataframes that apply to each.

I regularly do this for one dataframe by making my modifications, creating a dict of dataframes, and then exporting based on the key of the dict. The code I use looks something like:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df1.groupby('Key')))

for k, v in dfs.items():
    writer = ExcelWriter(k + '.xlsx')
    v.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='View 1', index=False)
```

I tried to do the same sort of thing with two dicts using the following code:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df1.groupby('Key')))
dfs_2 = dict(tuple(df2.groupby('Key')))

for k, v in dfs.items():
    writer = ExcelWriter(k + '.xlsx')
    v.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='View 1', index=False)

    for k, v in dfs_2.items():
        v.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='View 2', index=False)
```

This code gives me two tabs in Excel; however, only the first one exports properly. The second gives me the dataframe that I am looking for but with mismatched data. Not only does it not match the key of the first dict, but it doesn't appear to match any single key in the second dict either.

I also tried the following code:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df1.groupby('Key')))
dfs_2 = dict(tuple(df2.groupby('Key')))

for k, v in dfs.items():
    writer = ExcelWriter(k + '.xlsx')
    v.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='View 1', index=False)

    for k in dfs.items, v in dfs_2.items():
        v.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='View 2', index=False)
```

This code gave me the first dataframe, properly exported, on both tabs of the Excel file.

How can I get around this? The problems I am having are:

I) matching the keys and exporting the files properly

II) dealing with missing keys in different dataframes (i.e. not all keys will be in all dataframes, and which ones they are included in will change regularly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you do not relate the keys from either dictionaries. Considering employing such conditional `if` logic using one `for` iteration:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df1.groupby('Key')))
dfs_2 = dict(tuple(df2.groupby('Key')))

for k, v in dfs.items():
    writer = ExcelWriter(k + '.xlsx')
    v.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='View 1', index=False)

    # CHECK IF KEY EXISTS IN SECOND DICT AND CONDITIONALLY EXPORT ITEM VALUE
    if k in dfs_2:
        dfs_2[k].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='View 2', index=False)
```